# How to take the square of a number in Android

Tags: java, math, perfect-square

I'm trying to make a number squared (for example, x^2) in Android code, but I get this error:

The operator ^ is undefined for the argument type(s) int, boolean

is there a different way to square a number/variable in Android?

Comment: @David Elliot Use math package

Comment: Your error message seems to imply that `x` is a boolean.  You'll have a hard time squaring it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

do same as you do it in core java,use.
 `Math.pow(yournumber,power)` works like `yournumber^power`.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class MathDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  // get two double numbers
  double x = 2.0;
  double y = 5.4;

  // print x raised by y and then y raised by x
  System.out.println("Math.pow(" + x + "," + y + ")=" + Math.pow(x, y));// works like x^y
  System.out.println("Math.pow(" + y + "," + x + ")=" + Math.pow(y, x));//works like y^x

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use java's Math.pow() in android too

```
double power = Math.pow(2,2);
```

Comment: No offence, but will you please edit this and rephrase it like,"You can use java's math.pow() in android too".it seems like you are taking credits away from java...  :p

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an integer squared, you can do `x*x`.

Careful, as it might overflow.

Another option is [java.lang.Math#pow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29), but that works on floating point numbers.